# CORDA Start Flow through HTTP Endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, corda

I am trying to issue flow through HTTP endpoint. Basically I wan t to create a webserver where I can start a flow by passing some values to the http request. The parameters passed in the http query are the values for the State object along with the name of the owner (otherParty).

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/issue/{make}/{model}/{year}/{mile}/{vin}/{owner_name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    private String issueCar(@PathVariable String make, @PathVariable String model, @PathVariable int year, @PathVariable float mile, @PathVariable String vin, @PathVariable String owner_name){

        CordaX500Name ownerName = new CordaX500Name(owner_name, "New York", "US");
    Party owner = this.proxy.wellKnownPartyFromX500Name(ownerName);
    System.out.println(owner);

    this.proxy.startFlowDynamic(CarRegistrationFlowInitiator.class,make, model,year,mile,vin,owner);
    return "Flow Successful";
    }
```

I am currently unable to do so. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem you are facing? When you say unable to do so, what exarclty is the issue?

Comment: Following the documentation provided in https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.4/tutorial-cordapp.html#via-http ```

Comment: ok so what exception or error message when you try it with the above code

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the implementation of the controller with this CorDapp: https://github.com/corda/samples-java/blob/master/Accounts/tictacthor/clients/src/main/java/com/tictacthor/webserver/Controller.java

It is doing similar url Post calls as what you are trying to do there. Be sure to check if your server port and rpc port are correctly configured.

```
    @PostMapping(value = "requestGameWith/{whoAmI}/{team}/{competeWith}")
private ResponseEntity<String> requestGameWith(@PathVariable String whoAmI,@PathVariable String team, @PathVariable String competeWith){
    Set<Party> matchingPasties = proxy.partiesFromName(team,false);
    try{

        Iterator iter = matchingPasties.iterator();
        String result = proxy.startTrackedFlowDynamic(ShareAccountTo.class,whoAmI,iter.next()).getReturnValue().get();
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body("Game Request has Sent. When "+competeWith+" accepts your challenge, the game will start!");

    }catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity
                .status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
                .body(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```